# Как используя Django ORM выбрать поле с нулевым значением?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy

Есть ли возможность создать QuerySet от модели и определить в выборке поле все значения которого равны "0.0" не потеряв возможность работать с объектом запроса и его полями как с QuerySet? После объединения я хочу сделать "UNION ALL" с другой выборкой и посчитать сумму по полям 'plan' и 'fact'.

Какие ещё решения кроме RAW-запроса стоит рассмотреть?

```
from django.db.models import Model, ForeignKey, TextField, DecimalField, DateField, CASCADE

class ModelValueMixin(Model):
    date = DateField(auto_now=True)
    value = DecimalField()
    classifier = ForeignKey('Catalog', on_delete=CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelValue1(ModelValueMixin):
    pass

class ModelValue2(ModelValueMixin):
    pass

class Catalog(Model):
    code = TextField()
    name = TextField()
```

Пример того, как я это вижу с SQLAlchemy:

```
session.query(
    ModelValues1.value.label('plan'),
    literal_column('0').label('fact'),
    ModelCatalog.code.label('code'), 
    ModelCatalog.name.label('name')
).select_from(ModelValues1).outerjoin(ModelCatalog)
```

А непосредственно в SQL - вижу это вот так:

```
SELECT
  "catalog"."id",
  "catalog"."code",
  "catalog"."full_name",
  "values1"."value" AS "plan",
  (0) AS "fact"
FROM "catalog"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "values1"
    ON (catalog."id" = "values1"."catalog_id")
```

Конечная цель получить сводную таблицу с полями "код", "наименование", "сумма_план", "сумма_факт".

Comment: Покажите модели `ModelValues1` и `ModelCatalog`. И лучше расскажите подробнее, какого результата хотите добиться. А то есть стойкое ощущение, что вы изобретаете велосипед.

Comment: Добавил. Не уверен, что делаю это правильно, но буду рад, если порекомендуете иной способ для Django.

Comment: Итак, у вас есть каталоги, в каждом из которых может быть переменное количество каких-то значение. Для чего это? Что вы хотите посчитать?

Comment: Каталог с названием и кодом элемента, а так же две таблицы в одной из которых - плановые значения, а во второй - фактические. 
А получить хочу - сводную таблицу с суммарными значениями плана и факта для каждого элемента каталога.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил SQLAlchemy в проект и переписал сложные запросы на SQLAlchemy Core.

Вопрос решил - [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659296/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82-compoundselect-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-subquery/659302#659302). Удалось добится времени выполнения запроса менее чем за 100 мс.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужны [агрегация и аннотации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/). Должно получиться что-то вроде

```
from django.db.models import Sum

catalogs = Catalog.objects.annotate(plan=Sum(modelvalue1_set__value),
               fact=Sum(modelvalue2_set__value)).all()

for catalog in catalogs:
    print("{}: {}/{}".format(catalog.name, catalog.plan, catalog.fact))
```

Comment: Справедливо до того момента, пока у моделей со знначениями один каталог. У меня их может быть до десяти. Потому и изобретаю велосипед.

Comment: Поле `classifier` - это ForeignKey, оно может ссылать только на один каталог.

Comment: Я - неправильно объяснил. Может быть много полей вида `classifier_1`, `classifier_2`, `classifier_3`, и т. д. Поэтому сначала делаю две выборки, затем их объединяю и считаю сумму по значениям объединенных выборок.

Comment: Запрос который указан в вашем ответе преобразуется в нечто следующего вида `SELECT "app_classifier"."id", "app_classifier"."short_name", "app_classifier"."full_name", "app_classifier"."code" CAST(SUM("app_plan"."value") AS NUMERIC) AS "plan", CAST(SUM("app_fact"."value") AS NUMERIC) AS "fact" FROM "app_classifier" INNER JOIN "app_plan" ON ("app_classifier"."id" = "app_plan"."steward_id") INNER JOIN "app_fact" ON ("app_classifier"."id" = "app_fact"."steward_id") GROUP BY "app_classifier"."id", "app_classifier"."short_name", "app_classifier"."full_name", "app_classifier"."code"
`

Comment: Работает, к сожалению - медленно.