# Как от CompoundSelect получить subquery()?

Tags: python, postgresql

Хочу получить сводную таблицу с значениями код/наименование/план/факт/.

При попытке выполнить следующий код, при выполнении union_all() - получаем объект CompoundSelect, который не имеет метода subquery(). Как стоит переписать запрос, чтобы получить нужный результат?

```
meta = request.sa.base.metadata
classifier_table = Table('classifier', meta, autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=request.sa.engine)
plan_table = Table('revenueplan', meta, autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=request.sa.engine)
fact_table = Table('revenuefact', meta, autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=request.sa.engine)

_base_classifier_columns = [
    classifier_table.c.id.label('id'),
    classifier_table.c.full_name.label('name'),
    classifier_table.c.code.label('code')
]

_mock_null = literal_column(text='0')
_mock_null_plan = _mock_null.label(name='plan')
_mock_null_fact = _mock_null.label(name='fact')

_mock_at_start_of_year = datetime(datetime.now().year, 1, 1)
_mock_today = datetime.now()

_sum_plan = func.sum(plan_table.c.value).label('plan')
_sum_fact = func.sum(fact_table.c.value).label('fact')

_join_plan_w_classifier = join(classifier_table, plan_table, 
     classifier_table.c.id == plan_table.c.classifier_id)
_join_fact_w_classifier = join(classifier_table, fact_table, 
     classifier_table.c.id == fact_table.c.classifier_id)

_plan_1st = select(
    _base_classifier_columns + [
        plan_table.c.value.label('plan'), _mock_null_fact
     ]).select_from(_join_plan_w_classifier)\
     .where(between(plan_table.c.date, _mock_at_start_of_year, _mock_today))\
    .group_by(classifier_table.c.id)
 _fact_1st = select(
     _base_classifier_columns + [
         _mock_null_plan, fact_table.c.value.label('fact')
     ]).select_from(_join_fact_w_classifier)\
     .where(between(fact_table.c.date, _mock_at_start_of_year, _mock_today))\
     .group_by(classifier_table.c.id)
_union_year = union_all(_plan_1st, _fact_1st)
_sub_union_year = _union_year.subquery('_sub_union_year')
#                            ^
#                            Здесь ошибка, 
stmt = select([
    _sub_union_year.c.id,
    _sub_union_year.c.name,
    _sub_union_year.c.code,
    func.Sum(_sub_union_year.c.plan).label('plan'),
    func.Sum(_sub_union_year.c.fact).label('fact')
]).where.select_from(_sub_union_year).group_by(_sub_union_year.c.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вызвать метод [.cte()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CTE) для того чтобы запросить результат из выборки.

Группировку по id в первичной выборке нужно убрать.

```
_plan_1st = select(
    _base_classifier_columns + [plan_table.c.value.label('plan'), _mock_null_fact])\
    .select_from(_join_plan_w_classifier)\
    .where(between(plan_table.c.date, _mock_at_start_of_year, _mock_today))
_fact_1st = select(
    _base_classifier_columns + [_mock_null_plan, fact_table.c.value.label('fact')])\
    .select_from(_join_fact_w_classifier)\
    .where(between(fact_table.c.date, _mock_at_start_of_year, _mock_today))

union_year = union_all(_plan_1st, _fact_1st).cte('union_year')

stmt = select([
    union_year.c.id,
    union_year.c.name,
    union_year.c.code,
    func.sum(union_year.c.plan).label('plan'),
    func.sum(union_year.c.fact).label('fact')
])\
    .select_from(union_year)\
    .group_by(union_year.c.id, union_year.c.code, union_year.c.name)\
    .order_by(union_year.c.code)
```